# Unable to connect mongodb(DocumentDB-AWS) via kubernetes pod of microcks

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, aws-documentdb

I am getting below error when connecting to documentdb from microcks helm deployment.

I have selected the `mongodb:false` when deploying helm chart. Network seems to connecting.

Any suggestion?

```
08:00:16.002 [INFO] org.mongodb.driver.connection - Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:10}] to docdb-2022-12-.cluster-.ap-southeast-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017
08:00:16.007 [ERROR] io.github.microcks.web.HealthController - Health check caught an exception: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='mangodb', source='microcks', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='mangodb', source='microcks', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='mangodb', source='microcks', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='mangodb', source='microcks', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:140)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:3044)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:600)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doExactCount(MongoTemplate.java:1216)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doCount(MongoTemplate.java:1188)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.count(MongoTemplate.java:1178)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.count(MongoTemplate.java:1160)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.count(SimpleMongoRepository.java:175)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:255)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
```

Comment: Can you share your Helm chart? (sanitized of any private values)

Answer (score 0):

Disabled the SSL at documentdb or pass the ssl true as URI parameter in helm

Comment: How do you know that SSL coniguration is the issue? And how is the latter done if that is what OP desires?

Comment: One option for mongodb connection was to pass the mongodburi parameter which was commented, so when checking by default the SSL is enabled , so tried to disable it and tested so the results were good and pods are up and running